# How i use Angular DSCacheFactory in Ionic Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, browser-cache

I need to use `DSCacheFactory` in my Ionic/Cordova application. But I don't know how to use this. I also don't know much about `DSCacheFactory`,I think it same like web cache.

Please help me to found out solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of the ionic application use - [Angular Cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache). This is really a great library with most of the features we need in it already. It's simple to use and serves purpose.

Just do `npm install --save angular-cache`

or if you are using bower `bower install --save angular-cache`

The API's are very clean and intuitive.

**To store the data-**

```
profileCache.put('/profiles/34', {
    name: 'John',
    skills: ['programming', 'piano']
});
```

**To retrieve the stored data-**

```
var profile = profileCache.get('/profiles/34');

profile.name; // 'John'
```

**Get information about items in the cache-**

```
var info = profileCache.info('/profiles/34');

info.isExpired; // false
// etc.
```

**Get Information about the cache itself-**

```
var info = profileCache.info();

info.size; // 2
info.maxAge; // 3600000
info.deleteOnExpire; // 'aggressive'
// etc.
```

**Items can be removed easily, and we can destroy our cache when we're done with it-**

```
profileCache.remove('/profiles/34');

profileCache.get('/profiles/34'); // undefined

profileCache.destroy();

CacheFactory.get('profileCache'); // undefined
```

These are some of the most required or needed functions/operations. It has great support and is pretty stable. Thanks to [jmdobry](https://github.com/jmdobry) for such an elegant library.

Here are some reference links where in official forum of ionic people have suggested to use this library-

- [forum.ionicframework.com](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/module-angular-data-dscachefactory-is-not-available/21387/2)
- [Q about angular cache](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/angular-cache-error-typeerror-cannot-call-method-get-of-undefined-angular-cache/18159/3)
- [Q about Cache Factory](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cachefactory/6235)

Hope it helps :) Happy coding!

Comment: @SureshRatten Yes sure :) And if you have any issues, they are pretty quick in resolving issues. You can do so here- https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache/issues